# Draggable removed from div and dropped into a single droppable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a case where I'm dynamically creating "divs" and making them all draggable as a "class" contained within a "table". What I need to occur is for the drag to be free to drop into any one of the many droppable areas available. What is happening is when I drag the element it leaves a gap from the dragged area and when dropped; it drops multiple times instead of the one I place it in.

```
<html>
<head>
        <script>
    $(function() {
    $('.bills').draggable({
                    containment:"document"
    });

    $('.drop').droppable({
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            greedy: true,
            drop:function(event, ui) {
                ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($('.drop'));
            }
    });
    });
    </script>
</head>


<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Classroom 1</td>
<td><div class="drop"></div>
<td><div class="people">Johnny</div>
    <div class="people">Larry</div>
    <div class="people">Donald</div>
</td></tr></table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Classroom 2</td>
<td><div class="drop"></div>
<td><div class="people">Vince</div>
    <div class="people">Gerald</div>
    <div class="people">Kenny</div>
</td></tr></table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Classroom 1</td>
<td><div class="drop"></div>
<td><div class="people">Becky</div>
    <div class="people">Sabrina</div>
    <div class="people">Justin</div>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Been stuck on this and searching through stackoverflow for similar situation for two days any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you append items to `.drop` it will have the same behavior as when you wanted all items to be `draggable`, it will be dropped to all `div`s with class `drop`. You want to drop in the box you're currently dropping to, so you use `this` selector when event is called:

```
$('.drop').droppable({
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        greedy: true,
        drop:function(event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this)); //line changed
        }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/jkHS4/1/ disconsider the CSS since you didn't put here I made it minimal to show it working